# how to get the contents of the css from this example?

Tags: php, html, css

My php file

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

    $html = file_get_html("testhtml.txt");

    foreach ($html->find('link[rel="stylesheet"]') as $stylesheet)
    {
        echo $stylesheet_url = $stylesheet->href . '<br>';
        $tmp = $tmp . $stylesheet->href; 

    }
    $file = file_put_contents("css.txt",$tmp);
```

how to get the contents of the css with the help of above php file and place the text it another txt file?

Comment: `$css = file_get_contents($stylesheet->href)`, if allow_url_fopen is on

Answer (score -2):

you could load the content with a simple ajax get call, if stylesheet is included from the same domain
I tried this code (on FX10) as a proof of concept that use only one request to the CSS but it seems a bit hacky to me and should be tested and verified. it also should be improved with some fallback if javascript is not available.

**This is pure example of reading a css file through jquery**

CSS (external file test.css)

```
div { border: 3px solid red;}
```

HTML/jQuery

```
<!doctype html >
<html>
    <head>
       <!-- provide a fallback if js not available -->
       <noscript>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />
       </noscript>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div></div>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.when($.get("test.css"))
            .done(function(response) {
                $('<style />').text(response).appendTo($('head'));
                $('div').html(response);
            });
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I have already extract the css and save in a file. What I want is a php function to analyze css in terms of duplicate info, if all is called in html(class array-selected name, how many times they are being used)

Comment: Please help me Abhiseck